# Slash arguments in Nginx, PHP

Tags: php, apache, symfony, nginx

I'm trying to access this URL, after installing Symfony2:

```
http://test/symfony/web/app_dev.php/
```

But it won't work, because of the trailing slash, I get a 404.

These ones work fine:

```
http://test/symfony/web/app_dev.php
http://test/symfony/web/app_dev.php?/
```

In Apache, /app_dev.php/something and /app_dev.php?/something were the same. Any idea on how to make this work in Nginx?

I tried adding a rewrite, with no luck:

```
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite index.html;
    }

    location @rewrite {
            rewrite ^/(.*\.php)/(.*)$ $1?/$2;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have and it works fine:

```
    location / {
            # Remove app.php from url, if somebody added it (doesn't remove if asked for /app.php on the root)
            rewrite ^/app\.php/(.*) /$1 permanent;

            try_files $uri $uri/ /app.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri = 404;
            # Below is for fastcgi:
            # fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
            # fastcgi_index   app.php;
            # include         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            # fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME /mnt/www/live/current/web$fastcgi_script_name;
            # fastcgi_param   SERVER_PORT 80;
            # fastcgi_param   HTTPS off;
    }
```

Comment: The try_files line should be `try_files $uri =404` instead of `try_files $uri = 404`. Extra space would make nginx to look for `$document_root$uri`, `$document_root=`, `$document_root404`

Answer (score 0):

I finally stumbled across an answer that works for me:

```
    location ~ /directory/(.*\.php)(/.*)$ {
            set $script_filename $1;
            set $path_info $2;
            fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $2;
            alias /place/directory/$1;
            include fastcgi_params;
```

https://github.com/plack/Plack/issues/281

Here's the relevant snippet from the docs: note that none of them uses nginx-provided FCGI params for script_name or path_info since it's known to be incorrect.

```
location / {
 set $script "";
 set $path_info $uri;
 fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/fastcgi.sock;
 fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME      $script;
 fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $path_info;
```